# Google map heat map API requires multiple triggers to show up heat map

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have a heat map using Google heat map API. It was working sometimes as in I need to **refresh multiple times** and execute the draw heat map method then the heat map will come out. I included the script tag in html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=visualization,geometry"></script>
```

And here is the part where I initialize my map:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.352083,103.819836),
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      mapOptions);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

When my button show heat map button is onClick, I am plotting the heat map using this function:

```
var heatmap;
function plotEventHeatMap(){
var jsonArray = [];
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Together/TogetherServlet?action=GetEvents",
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
                var jsonObject = {};
                jsonObject.xcoord = jsondata.xcoord;
                jsonObject.ycoord = jsondata.ycoord;  
                jsonArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(jsonObject.ycoord, jsonObject.xcoord));
            });
        }
 });

 var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(jsonArray);

 heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray,
    map: map,
    radius: 40,
    gradient: gradient
 });

 heatmap.setMap(map);
 }
```

With these code, the heat map was working fine. Just that sometimes I have to repeat to refresh the browser and click on the draw heat map button multiple times to show up the heat map.

I wonder which part is causing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Down voter mind to explain?

Comment: Can you explain the expected result? Currently you draw each time when you call the function a new layer...is this really the desired result? Or do you want some kind of layer-toggling?

Comment: @Dr.Molle The heat map only worked only after a multiple times of refreshing the page and press on the button instead of I press on the button, and the heat map shows.

Comment: Check the network-connections. Your code uses ajax to fetch the points, what may take some time(maybe sometimes more time than expected). Inside your code is nothing that would explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is an asynchronous call. Your app fires a request to `"/Together/TogetherServlet?action=GetEvents"` but the script keeps running, and instances the Heatmap before the request returns any actual data, therefore you are creating a Heatmap with an empty jsonArray. The solution here is to instance the heatmap inside the ajax success handler.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Together/TogetherServlet?action=GetEvents",
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
                var jsonObject = {};
                jsonObject.xcoord = jsondata.xcoord;
                jsonObject.ycoord = jsondata.ycoord;  
                jsonArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(jsonObject.ycoord, jsonObject.xcoord));
            });
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(jsonArray);
            heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                data: pointArray,
                map: map,
                radius: 40,
                gradient: gradient
            });
        }
 });
```

Also, you don't really need to instance a new  heatmap on every function call. I suggest refreshing just its data

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
                 data: [],
                 map: null,
                 radius: 40,
                 gradient: gradient
              });

function updateHeatmap(){
    heatmap.setMap(null);    
    var jsonArray = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Together/TogetherServlet?action=GetEvents",
        type: "GET",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, jsondata) {
                var jsonObject = {};
                jsonObject.xcoord = jsondata.xcoord;
                jsonObject.ycoord = jsondata.ycoord;  
                jsonArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(jsonObject.ycoord, jsonObject.xcoord));
            });
            var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(jsonArray);
            heatmap.setData(pointArray);
            heatmap.setMap(map);
        }
    });
}
```